# JFace TreeViewer restore selection

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, treeviewer

I'm doing my first RCP example using the `TreeViewer` for directory browsing.

My work did start from the example http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecgui1/

For the `TreeViewer` of file entries I want to make the last selection persistent
to open the viewer by the same selection next time.

From the selected file I catched the path and store/retrieve this single string.

On reopening I traverse the `ITreeContentProvider` and find the corresponding
File node (and capture the nodes in between).

Next I use

```
window.getTree().setSelection(new StructuredSelection(target));
```

with target as a list of Files holding the path.

This works for the top level directories under C:

But restoring a deeper path fails. The next level is initially not
expanded and fails in the `AbstractTreeViewer.setSelectionToWidget()`.

My feeling is that I do not handle the `setSelection()` parameter well
but I found no suitable example.

Do you have a simple example for me showing how to restore such
a path selection?

thanks in advance

Wolfgang R.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it. The used example code has a small bug.

```
public class FileTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider
{
...
public Object getParent(Object element)
{
  // wrong return ((File)element).getParent();
  return ((File)element).getParentFile();
}
```